# how to read JSON-like data in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am implementing the cloud messaging of firebase on ios app, and I had received data variable`notification` like this:

`[AnyHashable("aps"): { alert = { body = Hello; title = "IOS Testing";};"mutable-content" = 1;}]`

does anyone know how to read data inside? it quite looks like a JSON file, but how can I read the body here? I tried notification["aps"]["alert"]["title"] and notification["aps"].alert.title. Both could not work. can someone please help me on this? Thank you!

Comment: For your information, it's not JSON like, it's how is printed a `NSDictionary` using the OpenStep writing. You can see it by doing `print(["alert": ["body": "Hello", "title": "iOS Testing"]] as NSDictionary)` What does it mean? It's already a NSDictionary, so it can be casted as a `Dictionary` (and so on for each of its values/keys).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```swift
guard
    let aps = data[AnyHashable("aps")] as? Dictionary,
    let alert = aps["alert"] as? Dictionary,
    let body = alert["body"] as? String,
    let title = alert["title"] as? String
    else {
        // handle any error here
        return
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! You literally saved my life! Could you please explain a little bit about this structure and what is NSDictionary here? I am pretty new to Swift. Thank you again!

Comment: You can check apple documentation. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary

Comment: Don’t use old NS... classes like NSDictionary when there are native swift alternatives

Comment: I'm not sure that `AnyHashable("aps")` is really needed. `data["data"]` should be enough.